# How can I save below write board(for signature) using core data

Tags: swift, core-data, swift3

I got this problem now. I don't know how to save below write board and and retrieve it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnkrH.png)

```
 override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    if let AppDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)
    {
        let context = AppDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        do{
            let results = try context.fetch(VisitorMO.fetchRequest())
            let signintime = results[lastnumber!] as? VisitorMO
//          signintime?.signinimage = imageView.image
            AppDelegate.saveContext()

        }catch{
            let nserror = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: is that signature is image?

Comment: Yes it is. Please let me know how to save it!!! thanks so much!!!!

Comment: attributes string what u assigned for image in core data? check if you assigned binary data or not, maybe that is an issue

Comment: it was "Binary data".

Comment: Why not save it in document folder?

Comment: Apple's [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html?utm_source=iosstash.io) will help you learn the basics of Core Data.

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
class ViewController: UIViewController {

   var logscreen: [NSManagedObject] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func saveImage(){
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
        }
        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        do{
            let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "CoreImage", in: managedContext)!
            let data = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: managedContext)
            data.setValue(imageview.image, forKeyPath: "image")
            try managedContext.save()
            logscreen.append(data)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            // failure
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

try this code for saving. also convert image into nsdata instead of imageview.image